# Print each item in list one second after the other (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Say I have a list of `n` items
I want to print each one after another with a second in between each

say `n = 5`:

```
list = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

I want "print list" to do

```
a 
...1 second... 
b 
..1 second...
c
...etc...
```

I have tried messing around with timer functions but im not sure what exactly to do

```
x = [a,b,c,d,e,f] 
for i in x
    print x
```

PS `C:\PYthon\A06> python -i test.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
>>> import time
>>> lis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for x in lis:
...     print x
...     time.sleep(1)
...     
a
b
c
d
e
```

---

Help on `time.sleep`:

```
sleep(seconds)

Delay execution for a given number of seconds.  The argument may be
a floating point number for subsecond precision.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`time.sleep()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) to pause execution for a given time:

```
import time

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for i in x:
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

`time.sleep()` takes an numeric argument, the number of seconds to 'sleep'.